# Rename files in a folder to one name

Tags: shell, unix

I have multiple .pdb files in different folders. How to loop in through entire directory naming all files to one particular name test.pdb?

Sample structure

```
file1 
 file1.pdb
 xyz.txt

file2
 file2.pdb 
 xyz.txt

file3
 file3.pdb
 xyz.txt
```

Desired output structure

```
file1
 test.pdb
 xyz.txt

file2
 test.pdb
 xyz.txt

file3
 test.pdb
 xyz.txt
```

The code I am using at the moment :

```
for d in */ ; do
    mv *.pdb test.pdb
done
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Inside your loop, you are always performing the identical command inside the directory from where you execute the loop. You never access any pdb file in a subdirectory. In addition, `mv *.pdb SOMETHING` would rename a file only if there is just a single pdb file matching the pattern. If there is more than one, SOMETHING must be a directory and the files are moved into this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the directory name. Just `*.pdb` will always expand to the files matching the wildcard in the current directory.

```sh
for d in ./*/ ; do
    mv "$d/"*.pdb "$d/"test.pdb
done
```

I added the `./` before the wildcard as a precaution too. It helps avoid problems if a file name starts with a dash, which would then get interpreted as an option to `mv` without the leading dash.

Many `mv` implementations will refuse to move multiple files to the same destination name, so this will probably only work if the wildcard expands to exactly one file in each directory. (Zero matches will work, but emit a noisy warning.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for d in */; do
  if [ -f $d/*.pdb ] ;then
    mv $d/*.pdb $d/test.pdb
  fi
done
```

Comment: This might work for the exact case described, but will break as soon as there is more than one `.pdb` file in a directory, and for any directory containing blanks or shell metacharacters (because of unquoted expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, iterating of the pdf files, instead of the folder names.

It's not clear if other pdb file, whose names does not match the folder name should be affected too. The code test for this condition. It can be removed if not needed.

```
for file in */*.pdb ; do
    d=$(dirname $file)
    b=$(basename $file .pdb)
    [ "$d" = "$b" ] && mv "$d/$b.pdb" "$d/test.pdb"
done
```